# Removing duplicate based on column but has to be the same for another column

Tags: python, pandas

I want to drop ids that have the same tag for the same company. The same id can appear twice.
I've tried this:

```
df.drop_duplicates(subset=['tag'], keep='last')
```

But there's a possibility that there might be another experiment that is a different company with the same tags. The solution above would delete that instance even though it's not considered a duplicate.

Input:

```
id  company   type       tag
1   Netflix   iPad       Includes dropdown
1   Netflix   iPad       Includes product list
2   Netflix   Tablet     Includes dropdown
2   Netflix   Tablet     Includes product list
3   Apple     iPad       Includes images
4   Apple     Tablet     Includes images
5   Facebook  Tablet     Includes dropdown
```

Output:

```
id  company   type       tag
2   Netflix   Tablet     Includes dropdown
2   Netflix   Tablet     Includes product list
3   Apple     iPad       Includes images
4   Apple     Tablet     Includes images
5   Facebook  Tablet     Includes dropdown
```

Comment: add the second column in the list. it should solve the problem

Answer (score 0):

Maybe what you want is to group the `company` and the `tag` column and be able to keep the set of values in the type given unique (company, tag) pairs. If so, then you can try:

```
x = [['1', 'Netflix', 'iPad', 'Includes dropdown'],
 ['1', 'Netflix', 'iPad', 'Includes product list'],
 ['2', 'Netflix', 'Tablet', 'Includes dropdown'],
 ['2', 'Netflix', 'Tablet', 'Includes product list'],
 ['3', 'Apple', 'iPad', 'Includes images'],
 ['4', 'Apple', 'Tablet', 'Includes images'],
 ['5', 'Facebook', 'Tablet', 'Includes dropdown']]

df = pd.DataFrame(x, columns =['id', 'company', 'type', 'tag']) 

df_new = pd.DataFrame([{'company':company, 'tag':tag, 'type':list(group['type'])} 
                       for (company, tag), group in df.groupby(['company', 'tag'])])
```

Output:

```
>>> df

id  company type    tag
0   1   Netflix iPad    Includes dropdown
1   1   Netflix iPad    Includes product list
2   2   Netflix Tablet  Includes dropdown
3   2   Netflix Tablet  Includes product list
4   3   Apple   iPad    Includes images
5   4   Apple   Tablet  Includes images
6   5   Facebook    Tablet  Includes dropdown

>>> df_new

    company     tag                     type
0   Apple       Includes images         [iPad, Tablet]
1   Facebook    Includes dropdown       [Tablet]
2   Netflix     Includes dropdown       [iPad, Tablet]
3   Netflix     Includes product list   [iPad, Tablet]
```

Note: Use `'type':set(group['type']` if you want unique type values.

---

You can also use `aggregate`:

```
from itertools import chain 

def sum_str(*strings):
    return list(chain(*strings))

df.groupby(['company', 'tag']).agg({'type': sum_str})
```

Depending on what you want, this might help too:

```
from itertools import chain 

def sum_str(*strings):
    return set(chain(*strings))

df.groupby(['company']).agg({'type': sum_str, 'tag': sum_str})
```

[out]:

```
                    type    tag
company     
Apple       {iPad, Tablet}  {Includes images}
Facebook    {Tablet}        {Includes dropdown}
Netflix     {iPad, Tablet}  {Includes product list, Includes dropdown}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you want to create an artificial identifier by combining company and tag, you could try as follows:

Code:

```
from io import StringIO
import pandas as pd

if __name__ == '__main__':
    input_data = StringIO("""id  company   type       tag
1   Netflix   iPad       Includes dropdown
1   Netflix   iPad       Includes product list
2   Netflix   Tablet     Includes dropdown
2   Netflix   Tablet     Includes product list
3   Apple     iPad       Includes images
4   Apple     Tablet     Includes images
5   Facebook  Tablet     Includes dropdown""")

    df = pd.read_csv(input_data, sep="\s{2,}", engine="python")
    df.drop_duplicates(subset=["company", "tag"], keep="last", inplace=True)
    print(df)
```

Result:

```
   id   company    type                    tag
2   2   Netflix  Tablet      Includes dropdown
3   2   Netflix  Tablet  Includes product list
5   4     Apple  Tablet        Includes images
6   5  Facebook  Tablet      Includes dropdown
```